Listening to TCP traffic in a different port than 282
Listening to TCP traffic in a different port than 282
I'm using Pcap++ to listen to TCP traffic for my application. So far it all worked well and I am able to instantiate a pcpp::PcapLiveDevice and receive traffic. This is, provided that I run my application using sudo.
If I run it without sudo, I get the following error:
[ERROR: /../PcapPlusPlus/Pcap++/src/PcapLiveDevice.cpp: doOpen:282] socket: Operation not permitted
[ERROR: /../PcapPlusPlus/Pcap++/src/PcapLiveDevice.cpp: doOpen:282] socket: Operation not permitted
Cannot open device
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

As I understand, the program is trying to bind port 282 for TCP communication but this cannot happen unless it has root privileges.
My question is: Is there any way to instantiate the pcpp::PcapLiveDevice so it binds a different port (>1024) so it doesn't require root access?
I'm running in Ubuntu 22.04.
This sample should be able to reproduce the issue:
CMakeList.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(pcap_listener)

# Set C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
# popen()/pclose() are not C++ standards
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)

find_package(PcapPlusPlus REQUIRED)

add_executable(pcap_listener pcap_listener.cpp)
set_target_properties(pcap_listener PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                                               "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(pcap_listener PUBLIC PcapPlusPlus::Pcap++)


pcap_listener.cpp
#include "PcapLiveDeviceList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Packet.h"
#include "TcpLayer.h"
#include "SystemUtils.h"

static bool tcp_callback(pcpp::RawPacket * packet, pcpp::PcapLiveDevice * dev, void * cookie)
{
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  pcpp::PcapLiveDevice * dev =
    pcpp::PcapLiveDeviceList::getInstance().getPcapLiveDeviceByName("lo");
  if (dev == nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot find interface lo" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  if (!dev->open()) {
    std::cerr << "Cannot open device" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  int timeout = 6000;   //seconds
  dev->startCaptureBlockingMode(tcp_callback, nullptr, timeout);

}


Nothing to do with ports or listening. You can’t open the device that Pcap uses to peek the traffic.

This has nothing to do with the port. Packet capturing simply requires root privileges - or at least the right capabilities. See Does Linux support capturing tcp packets without being super user?

"As I understand, the program is trying to bind port 282 for TCP communication" No.  "doOpen:282" is referring to line 282 of PcapLiveDevice.cpp in PcapPlusPlus, which is in the doOpen routine.  See https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/blob/e48be80c8671ca2018db24947c7d71df9c41b1fd/Pcap%2B%2B/src/PcapLiveDevice.cpp#L282.  That's an error from libpcap; the socket being opened is probably a PF_PACKET socket if this is on Linux; that's a special socket for capturing raw packets, not a TCP socket.  As noted, opening a PF_PACKET socket requires special privileges.
